# Python- Need to search a list for adjacent duplicate values and replace the adjacent

Tags: python, list

this is an example list:

```
mylist = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1]
```

I need to search the list for adjacent 0 until no zeros are adjacent. My needed output-

```
newlist = [0,x,1,0,1,0,x,x,1,0,x,x,x,1,0,x,x,1,0,1,0,x,1]
```

so I retain a single zero at its correct index, but replace its adjacents with "x". I am new to python and have take some very unsuccessful stabs at it.

I tried creating a while loop but I'm sad cuz bad.

Comment: Seems odd to build a list with different types of elements. What are you going to do with it?

Comment: I am working on a dimensioning automation in Revit, and sometimes it grabs multiple references at the same location, resulting in  0 value dimensions. I dont want to filter out all of the zeros, because one of those zeros is generating a valid dimension if the others around it dont exist, so I am using this list for a bool mask to just filter out adjacent 0 values

Comment: So you actually want a bool list, not the list you've shown?

Comment: in the end yes, but I am using this inside of Dynamo for Revit, so I am more comfortable feeding this into a node. Im very new to Python

Answer (score 1):

Zip the list together with a lagged copy of itself and use a list comprehension to produce the new list:

```
newlist = ["x" if a == b == 0 else b for a, b in zip([None] + mylist, mylist)]
```

I understood from your question that you are only looking for duplicate zeroes. But if you want to replace all duplicates, just remove the `== 0`:

```
newlist = ["x" if a == b else b for a, b in zip([None] + mylist, mylist)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [**`itertools.groupby()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1]
new_list = []

for _, j in  groupby(mylist):
    new_list.append(next(j))
    for _ in j:
        new_list.append('x')
 
# which will return you `new_list` as: 
#    [0, 'x', 1, 0, 1, 0, 'x', 'x', 1, 0, 'x', 'x', 'x', 1, 0, 'x', 'x', 1, 0, 1, 0, 'x', 1]
```

Here's an one liner to achieve this with additional usage of [**`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain 

new_list = list(chain.from_iterable((next(j), *['x' for _ in j]) for _, j in  groupby(mylist)))

# which will return you `new_list` as: 
#   [0, 'x', 1, 0, 1, 0, 'x', 'x', 1, 0, 'x', 'x', 'x', 1, 0, 'x', 'x', 1, 0, 1, 0, 'x', 1]
```

Comment: Not sure why your first solution would be more efficient. How about `list(chain.from_iterable([i] + ["x"] * (len(list(j))-1) for i, j in groupby(mylist)))` to avoid the inner loop?

Comment: @Stuart although using the list function in many cases is more efficient than using a standard python loop it still performs a loop in the background. Also, you're creating copies of the same `'x'` variable using that method.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the most simple and efficient solution. Using the walrus operator to assign the last number seen during iteration in a comprehension.

```
my_list = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1]

last = None
output = ['x' if last == n else (last := n) for n in my_list]
```

Output:

```
[0, 'x', 1, 0, 1, 0, 'x', 'x', 1, 0, 'x', 'x', 'x', 1, 0, 'x', 'x', 1, 0, 1, 0, 'x', 1]
```